# YouTube PHP video browser API: Thumbnails not showing & reordering to most recent?

Tags: php, api, youtube, playlist

Hi I have created a YouTube video browser from a playlist, you can view the current progress on this page. A few things I need help with though!

1. <strike>The thumbnails aren't showing, videos are there (hover, you'll see the titles).</strike>
2. How can I order the videos by most recent first? It's currently doing the opposite.

Help would be greatly apreciated! Visual of what it's going to look like in the end: i.stack.imgur.com/xKpVg.png

The code currently is:

```
<style type="text/css">
#videos{background:gray;width:299px}
#videos a:hover
</style>

<div id="videos">
<?php get_playlists(); ?>
</div>

<?php

function get_playlists(){
$data = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/C82EBDAC0429B6A2?max-results=12");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->entry as $playlist){
    $media = $playlist->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
    $thumb = $attrs['url'];
    $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
    $video = $attrs['url'];
    $title = $media->group->title;

$url = $video;
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
$vid_Id = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

$thumbnail .= '<div style="float:left; cursor:pointer;">
<a href="/tutorials/view_tutorial.php?id=' . $vid_Id . '">
<img src="' .$thumb . '" title="' . $title . '" width="74" height="42"
</a>
</div>';

    }

    print $thumbnail;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image `img` tag is missing a = on the `src` attribute.

```
<img src"' .$thumb . '" title="' . $title . '" width="74" height="42"
```

Should be

```
<img src="' .$thumb . '" title="' . $title . '" width="74" height="42"
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I've updated the file accordingly. Do you know how to alter the script so it shows the most recent videos first?

Comment: I don't think thats possible - not in the way you want anyway. You'd have to add all the videos to an array with the published date as they key and then order it in PHP. However, thats outside the scope of this question - you should accept this one and open a new question for further help :)

Comment: Haha ok, thanks for your help anyway! It's got me that little bit further!